# VsCode not detecting syntax error in React props

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code

Is there anyway to detect typos in React Native props. For example, here I wrote "styl" instead of "style" and it doesn't show any error. Is there a way to fix that? I've tried using EsLint but it still doesn't help with this, Is there something in the settings I need to change?

[image: example]

Comment: Please post your code not as image. Copy and paste the code in code tags.